# Using System.Net's HttpClient in a Universal App, is there a way to specify ClientCertificate manually?

Tags: c#

In a Universal App (Windows Store, Windows Phone), I can use Windows.Web's HttpClient and use HttpBaseProtocolFilter to specify the client certificates. For example

```
        var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
        filter.ClientCertificate = ...
```

However, to avoid a lot of #ifs I would like to use the System.Net HttpClient. In Universal Apps and PCLs, WebRequestHandler is not available, only HttpClientHandler. How can I manually specify the Client Certificate? In this case I would like the certificate to be confined to my application.

Incidentally, in old style .NET I would use

```
        var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(...);
```

But this is only available in System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll.

**Note.** The answer may well be, sorry, there is no way to manually set ClientCertificate using System.Net for Universal Apps. :P